# elasticsearch returns null on stats aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, statsd

I have small data of 1200 entries in Elasticsearch that is automatically input in mapped fields of document-types. The float goes in float and double goes in double.
When taking 'aggs' of the data on 'stats' like:

```
GET /statsd-2015.09.28/timer_data/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : { "match_all" : {}},
                "filter" : {
                    "range" : { "ns" : { "lte" : "gunicorn" }}
                }
            }
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "value_val" : { "stats" : { "field" : "u'count_90'" } }
        }
}
```

I get null on return like this:

```
...  
"aggregations": {
      "value_val": {
         "count": 0,
         "min": null,
         "max": null,
         "avg": null,
         "sum": null
      }
   }
...
```

Here is my mapping of fields:

```
{"statsd-2015.09.28":{"mappings":{"timer":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"string"},"act":{"type":"string"},"grp":{"type":"string"},"ns":{"type":"string"},"tgt":{"type":"string"},"val":{"type":"float"}}},"gauge":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"string"},"act":{"type":"string"},"grp":{"type":"string"},"ns":{"type":"string"},"tgt":{"type":"string"},"val":{"type":"float"}}},"counter":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"string"},"act":{"type":"string"},"grp":{"type":"string"},"ns":{"type":"string"},"tgt":{"type":"string"},"val":{"type":"float"}}},"timer_data":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"double"},"act":{"type":"string"},"count":{"type":"float"},"count_90":{"type":"float"},"count_ps":{"type":"float"},"grp":{"type":"string"},"lower":{"type":"float"},"mean":{"type":"float"},"mean_90":{"type":"float"},"median":{"type":"float"},"ns":{"type":"string"},"std":{"type":"float"},"sum":{"type":"float"},"sum_90":{"type":"float"},"sum_squares":{"type":"float"},"sum_squares_90":{"type":"float"},"tgt":{"type":"string"},"upper":{"type":"float"},"upper_90":{"type":"float"}}}}}}
```

What I want to ask is that why is my output not desired? And how can I get it?

Comment: I see from you mapping that your field is called `count_90`, or is it `u'count_90'` like you wrote in the aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /statsd-2015.09.28/timer_data/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : { "match_all" : {}},
                "filter" : {
                    "range" : { "ns" : { "lte" : "gunicorn" }}
                }
            }
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "value_val" : { "stats" : { "field" : "count_90" } }
        }
}
```

I am new to this but I realized that field name was not what I was using. After this, everything became clear.